# How to return JsonModel by default in ZF2?

Tags: json, zend-framework2, zend-view

Default ViewModel is not mandatory, I can return from controller just the array of data:

```
public function someAction()
{
  //...
  return array('result'=>$data);
}
```

But I can`t use this approach with Json. What should I do in dispatch event to wrap the results in JsonModel (for the appropriate accept header)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just create Base Controller for all your API controllers, and replace model in MvcEvent.

```
class JsonRestController extends AbstractRestfulController
{

    public function onDispatch(MvcEvent $e)
    {
        $e->setViewModel(new JsonModel());
        return parent::onDispatch($e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to add a ViewJsonStrategy strategy to the view manager under your module.config.php:

```
'view_manager' => array(
    'template_map'              => array(
    ),
    'template_path_stack'       => array(
        __DIR__ . '/../view',
    ),
    'strategies'                => array(
        'ViewJsonStrategy',
    ),
),
```

Then you can return a JsonModel in your action:

```
public function myAction()
{
    $data = [1, 2, 3, 4];

    return new JsonModel([
        'data' => $data
    ]);
}
```

Comment: my question is - how can I avoid of manual using of JsonModel on every return? I work on API module now so I don`t need any other view type except JSON or XML

Answer (score 1):

to get json data from controller you can echo json encoded data and exit. I use that for jquery ajax. i hope this is what you are looking for.

```
public function testAction()
{
    $active = "some data";
    echo json_encode(array('result' => $active));
    exit();
}
```

then at jquery you can get this data like that

```
$.ajax({
              type: 'GET',
              url: '/index/time',
              dataType: 'json',
              error: function() {
                 $('#info').html('<p>Error on time calculation</p>');
              },
              success: function(data) {
                  data.result
              }
 });
```

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others.

Comment: thank you, i am new here. I will try to consider your suggestion after now.

Comment: why you use exit? instead you can do "return json_encode(...);"

Comment: I would say its alot better do return a JsonModel since that will also set the right headers in the response.

Answer (score 0):

Is really simple

Add as follows:

**IndexController.php**

```
use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;
use Zend\View\Model\JsonModel; // Add this line

class IndexController extends AbstractActionController {

    public function indexAction() {
        // some index action
        return new ViewModel();
    }

    public function apiAction() {

        $person = array(
            'first_name' => 'John',
            'last_name' => 'Downe',
        );
        // Special attention to the next line
        return new JsonModel(array(
            'data' => $person,
        ));
    }

}
```

**api.phtml**

```
<?php echo $this->json($this->data); ?>
```

**Result:**

```
{"first_name":"John","last_name":"Downe"}
```